# preg_match only some numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to write preg_match function for this BNF grammar.

> EXP    ::= EXP  + TERM   | EXP - TERM    | TERM
>
> TERM   ::= TERM * FACTOR | TERM / FACTOR | FACTOR
>
> FACTOR ::= ( EXP ) | DIGIT
>
> DIGIT  ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3

I tried to write it this way

> $pattern  = "|[0-3+-()*/]+\$$|";

but the problem with this is , it accepts string 33$ which is not valid as per my grammar
so as per my grammar 1+22$ should not be valid because number should be 0|1|2|3.

what mistake I am making? can somebody please help me.

Edit:

Example:
1+22$ should be invalid string because I just want numbers 0,1,2,3 but not any number > 3

Thank you.

Comment: Give an example of what you have & what output you expecting ?

Comment: Why not just run the tokenizer/parser and see if it parses ok? Regex is a poor substitute for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern?

```
/^([0-3][+-*/])+[0-3]\$$/
```

solution with parenths not trivial for regexp;

```
/^(\(?[0-3]\)?[+-*/])+[0-3]\)\$$/
```

allow you to create right expressions like a (2+3)$ but also wrong (2+3$

write your own lexer for this

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/[^.\d]/i", "text123");
```

result - 123